# Comparing max of column with another column

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to compare two string columns in Mongodb using aggregate. My job is to list all docs which have a field(field1) greater than max of another field/column(field2).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
                         {"$match": {"id": "XXX"}},
                         {"$match": {"$expr": {'$gt': ["$field1", {"$max": '$field2'}]}}},
                         {"$project": {"id":1, "field1":1}}])
```

This doesn't seem to work. I'm using MongoDB 4.

Comment: What do you mean by `max` on a string column ? I would say this question is more easy to understand with sample input docs & required o/p !!

Comment: To use the `$max` aggregation operator the `field2` _must_ be an array; see the documentation on [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/index.html#array-operand).

Comment: @prasad_ That's condition for $project, is that also for $match. I don't see example for $match here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/

Comment: The `$project` and `$match` stage conditions can have the same operators when the `$match` uses the `$expr` operator. Note that `$expr` is for using the _aggregation operators_ within `$match` stage. If you don't use the `$expr` operator in the `$match` stage, then the operators used must be from the MongoDB Query Language (i.e., the operators from the `find` method). Once again, see the `$max` documentation  from the top of the page - somewhere it mentions that _"$max is available in $match stage that includes an $expr expression"_.